# What does "common" mean in kotlin documentation?

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin standard library documentation i can see the following filters:
[image]

As far as i can gather, JVM means that internals of a package can be compiled into byte code, JS into javaScript and Native into binaries. **But what does "Common" mean ?**

Answer (score 3):

`Common` means available for all platforms. It is an API that you can use directly in platform independent code in [Kotlin Multiplatform](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) projects.
Kotlin Multiplatform allows you to write common Kotlin code for multiple different platforms. For example, you could have a project with an Android app (using Kotlin/JVM for native Android applications) and a web interface (using Kotlin/JS). Then, you could share code between both subprojects.

As you have guessed correctly, `JVM` means it is available using Kotlin/JVM (compiling to Java bytecode).

If it is marked with `JS`, it is available for [Kotlin/JS](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-overview.html) which transpiles the Kotlin code to JavaScript.

Finally, `Native` means it is available when using [Kotlin/Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-overview.html). This is different from compiling with `native-image`, which compiles JVM bytecode to native executables. For that, you would still use Kotlin/JVM.

Comment: `For example, you could have a project with an Android app (using Kotlin/JVM for native Android applications) and a web interface (using Kotlin/JS). Then, you could share code between both subprojects.` Isn't this effect due to a package marked as "JS" and "JVM" ?

Comment: Also what does marking only as "common" and "native",which `kotlin.native` package has, mean. "Common" means all platforms but absence of both "JS" and "JVM" imply only "Native". It confuses.

Comment: `Isn't this effect due to a package marked as "JS" and "JVM" ?` - you can have seperate folders like `commonXYZ` (e.g. `commonMain`) and code from those folders can be used from both JVM and JS sources.

Comment: If you [take a look at `kotlin.native`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.native/) and filter for elements marked with `Common`, you can see that there are only annotations (that seem to be mainly regarding Objective-C/Swift so I guess it is used for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile).

Answer (score 1):

If you write code in "common", then it can be compiled into any of the other targets, so you can share Kotlin code amongst the different platforms you are targeting. You can read more in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-share-on-platforms.html).

Comment: Then what does marking only as "common" and "native",which kotlin.native has, mean. "Common" means all platforms but absence of both "JS" and "JVM" imply only "Native". It confuses.

Comment: Do you have an example? That would normally be something that you could use in common code, but would only have an effect when compiled for a native target. For instance an annotation could have no effect if compiled for JVM, but would if compiled for a native target.

Comment: by `kotlin.native`, i meant a package from the kotlin standard library that is so called.

Comment: Anyway i have understood. If a package ,for example, only has a "Common" and "Native" tag, it means that while compiling to js or bytecode there will not be a crash but the code from that package will not have an effect.

Comment: Yeah... I suspect the only declarations which are available for only common and native are annotations. So it wouldn't be unnatural for those to have no effect on the other platforms. Maybe also there may be implementations of interfaces only provided for some platforms.